# Wait for a controller to run all of its code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I want to know if there is a way that lets say controller 2 waits for controller 2 to finish running all of its code.
Im making mobile app, when a user logs in, the app goes to the home page which has a tabbar that loads 4 controllers, but they are loading all at the same time, controller 1 loads a part, then controller 2 shows up loading more, problem is that I am making `HTTP` request to get data and fill the HTML with the data.

```
aldro_app.controller('ctrTabBarOpciones', function($scope, compartidosFactory, $http, $rootScope){

console.log('controller tabbar');

$scope.comprobarTab = function (tab) {
    compartidosFactory.tab = tab;
}

    var id = parseInt(getVariable("idcontrato"));
    var url = "http://api/info";
    $http({
    url : url,
    method: "POST",
    data: {id_contrato: id},
    headers:{
     "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
     "Authorization": "Bearer " + getVariable("token")
    }
    })
    .then(function(response){
    console.log("Facturas del contrato -> " + id + "son: " + response.data);
    setVariable("facturas" , JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
  });
```

this is the first controller that loads (I know it because on the console the first thing to show is "controller tabbar"), and I am saving the data I am getting on localStorage with the `setVariable` function, problem comes here.

```
aldro_app.controller('ctrInicio', function ($scope,$http, $rootScope) {
     /* Http para retirar las ultimas facturas del contrato */
     console.log("Inicio controller");
     //console.log(x.facturas.length);
           var objeto = getVariable("facturas");
           deleteVariable("facturas");
           var listado_facturas = JSON.parse(objeto);
           var arr_length = listado_facturas.facturas.length;
      });
```

I am getting error of `Cannot read property 'facturas' of undefined` because my `ctrTabbarOpciones` loads at first but then my `ctrInicio` shows up running his code that needs the code which has not been executed yet in `ctrTabbarOpciones` so, how to tell my controller to wait for the other controller? (Sorry for grammar mistakes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast an event from first controller and listen to it on second controller. 3

```js
aldro_app.controller('ctrTabBarOpciones', function($scope, compartidosFactory, $http, $rootScope){

console.log('controller tabbar');

$scope.comprobarTab = function (tab) {
    compartidosFactory.tab = tab;
}

    var id = parseInt(getVariable("idcontrato"));
    var url = "http://api/info";
    $http({
    url : url,
    method: "POST",
    data: {id_contrato: id},
    headers:{
     "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
     "Authorization": "Bearer " + getVariable("token")
    }
    })
    .then(function(response){
    console.log("Facturas del contrato -> " + id + "son: " + response.data);
    setVariable("facturas" , JSON.stringify(response.data));
        $rootScope.$broadcast('received data'); // broadcast event
    })
  });
```

```js
aldro_app.controller('ctrInicio', function ($scope,$http, $rootScope) {
     /* Http para retirar las ultimas facturas del contrato */
     console.log("Inicio controller");
     //console.log(x.facturas.length);
     $rootScope.$on('receivedData', function(){
      var objeto = getVariable("facturas");
           deleteVariable("facturas");
           var listado_facturas = JSON.parse(objeto);
           var arr_length = listado_facturas.facturas.length;
     })
          
      });
```

Comment: My `HTTP` request in `ctrTabBarOpciones` is executed after the `ctrInicio`

Comment: Yeah, But you are triggering an event now and listening it in ctrInicio, so it shouldnt cause any problem. Whenever you get the data , it executes the function in ctrInicio

Comment: this did it in a way, proble is now that I am trying to access `listado_facturas` a little later in my `ctrInicio`, now a dumb question maybe, on my $on event, can I declare another function?